# Какой алгоритм использовать для решения задачи?

Tags: олимпиада

[image: Условие задачи]

и я не могу понять что именно нужно вывести

Comment: Ладно, Вы просите решить задачу за Вас. Но Вы поленились даже переписать ее, а вместо этого бросаетесь скриншотами

Comment: классическая задача на графы.

Comment: Что нужно вывести: вывести вершины по которым робот перемещается - первая строчка. Последняя говорит о длине пройденного пути. Можно решить через графы, можно через градиент - ещё легче, ведь всё на плоскости. Для определения пройденного пути достаточно формулы Пифагора, второй класс третья четверть. Задача типичная, это даже не олимпиада, такие наверняка были в году 2012-м...

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вроде в вопросе написано "Какой **алгоритм** использовать" а не **решите мне** ....... Но вместо скриншота лучше текстом описать задачу, это точно

Comment: @KoVadim то есть может подойти алгоритм А* или волновой?

Comment: При таком количестве точек даже перебор будет быстрым :)

Comment: @KoVadim На графы - поиск цикла Гамильтона - это ж вроде как NP?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне понравилась идея @Qwertiy с permutation. Написал бегло код (код очень грязный, писан левой ногой, но посчитало все верно).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

double dist(point x, point y) {
    return hypot(x.x-y.x, x.y-y.y);
}

double calc_len(const vector<point> &v, const vector<int> &d) {
    double l = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < d.size(); i++) {
        l += dist(v[d[i-1]], v[d[i]]);
    }
    return l;
}

int main() {
    vector<point> v;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        point p;
        cin >> p.x >> p.y;
        v.push_back(p);
    }
    vector<int> d;
    vector<int> min_r;
    double min_len = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    for (int i = 0; i< n; i++) { d.push_back(i); }
    do {
        double len = calc_len(v, d);
        cout << len << endl;
        if (len < min_len) {
            min_len = len;
            min_r = d;
        }
    } while ( std::next_permutation(begin(d)+1,end(d)-1) );
    cout << "len = " << min_len << endl;
    cout << "[";
    for (int x:min_r) { cout << " " << x+1; }
    cout << "]" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

вычисление расстояния в с++11 можно писать уже так

```
double dist(point x, point y) {
    return hypot(x.x-y.x, x.y-y.y);
}
```

а не так

```
double dist(point x, point y) {
    return sqrt((x.x-y.x) * (x.x-y.x) + (x.y-y.y) * (x.y-y.y));
}
```

P.S. компилировать нужно с поддержкой с++11.

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что hypot рекомендовали не использовать, т. к. он медленный...

Comment: next_permutation на векторе в дебаге - тормозит. Иногда лучше массив использовать...

Comment: @Qwertiy с чего бы?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а зачем в дебаге? Впрочем, согласен, что массив. Ну говорили так, как раз на олимпиадном программировании. Как и cin/cout, кстати.

Comment: @Qwertiy затем, что отлаживать-то как-то программу надо. А для малых N часто даже тест не составишь нормальный...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в соседнем ответе замерили hypot.

Comment: hypot медленный, потому что он дает некоторые гарантии (например, на переполнение). Замена его назад на вычисление в лоб дает до 30 раз ускорение. Но в данном случае это все не принципиально - основная задача олимпиад не написать самый быстрый код, а написать код, который уложится в требуемые временные рамки и, обычно, нужно это сделать самым первым.

Comment: @KoVadim можно ли как нибудь заменить next_permutation, я хочу переписать код на java но там нет такого метода

Comment: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3980?locale=ru

Answer (score 3):

Это [задача Коммивояжёра](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0), решается перебором (с отсечениями).

С учётом того, что точки на плоскости, можно ещё что-нибудь пооптимизировать, но при n<=12 не думаю, что это имеет смысл.

Comment: Что-то мне припоминается, что на плоскости можно как-то быстрее... Нет? А, нет, соврал. При условии неравенства треугольника есть быстрые приближенные алгоритмы...

Comment: @Harry, у меня есть подозрение, что да, но я не помню. Но тут же 12. Да ещё и лексикографически наименьший путь. Не уверен даже, насколько хорошо тут маску с посещёнными вершинами использовать - может лексикографичность портить.

Comment: @Harry, можно. К тому же сложность перебора с отсечениями будет равна большому количеству всё равно. Например, если известно, что требуется найти простые пути, и если n = 12, то алгоритм будет считать очень и очень долго.  Я такое делал.

Comment: @VostokSisters Две точки - крайние, посредине - 10. 10! - это немного :)

Comment: @Harry, блин, вот я формулу для расчета переборов выводил года 3 назад, но найти не могу. Вообщем, это не многим меньше, чем 12! А 12! - это дофига. 10! - да, за секунды у меня простые пути искал, перебирая все варианты с усечениями. 12! искал минуты 2. А дальше уже долго и долго.

Comment: @Harry, можно даже [next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) применить.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрел на @KoVadim и тоже набросал на коленке - ветвление с отсечениями...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct pnt { double x, y; };

double dist(pnt a, pnt b)    // Расстояние между точками
{
    return hypot(a.x-b.x,a.y-b.y);
}

double path_len(const vector<pnt>& x, // Длина (части) выбранного пути
                const vector<int>& p, size_t l)
{
    double pl = 0.0;
    for(size_t i = 1; i <= l; ++i)
        pl += dist(x[p[i-1]],x[p[i]]);
    // Расстояние до последней точки, если еще не достали
    if (l != p.size()-1) pl += dist(x[p[l]],x[x.size()-1]);
    return pl;
}

struct Func
{
    double min;               // Текущее минимальное расстояние
    const vector<pnt> * r;    // Массив точек
    vector<int>         save; // Сохраненная перестановка

    Func(const vector<pnt>& x):r(&x)
    {
        min = 0.0;
        for(size_t i = 1; i < x.size(); ++i)
            min += dist(x[i-1],x[i]);
    }

    // Проверка ветви
    bool operator()(const vector<int>& x, size_t l)
    {
        // Режем все, где неверное начало или конец
        if (x[0] != 0) return false;
        if (l != x.size()-1 && x[l] == x.size() - 1) return false;
        // Текущая длина
        double cur = path_len(*r,x,l);
        // Если больше минимальной - режем ветвь
        if (cur > min + min*DBL_EPSILON) return false;
        // Сохранение нового пути
        if (l == x.size()-1)
        {
            if (abs(min-cur) < 10.0*min*DBL_EPSILON)
            {
                if (save > x) save = x;
            }
            else
            {
                min = cur;
                save = x;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

// Ветвление и обрезка
template<typename Func>
bool branches(size_t N, Func& f, vector<int>*v_ = nullptr, size_t level = 0)
{
    // Вспомогательный вектор
    vector<int> * vv = (level == 0) ? new vector<int> : v_;
    if (level == 0) for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) vv->push_back(i);
    vector<int>& v = *vv;

    for(size_t i = level; i < N; ++i)
    {
        // Очередная перестановка
        std::swap(v[level],v[i]);
        if (f(v,level) && level < N-1) branches(N,f,vv,level+1);
        std::swap(v[i],v[level]);

    }
    if (level == 0) delete vv;
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<pnt> x;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout <<"Point " << (i+1) << ": ";
        double xx, yy;
        cin >> xx >> yy;
        x.push_back(pnt{xx,yy});
    }
    Func f(x);
    branches(N,f);
    cout << f.min << endl;
    for(auto i: f.save) cout << (i+1) << "  ";
    cout << endl;

}
```

На входных данных с 13 точками отработал за полсекунды, перебор @KoVadim - 37 секунд; для 12 точек - 0.17 и 3.1 секунды соответственно...

**Update**
Данные для эксперимента -

```
13
0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 0 2 1 2 2 2 3 2 0 3 1 3 2 3 3 3
```

(я просто работал до 16 точек, ну, чтоб не переписывать файл с данными - менял только первое число)

Компиляция - VC++ 2015, ключики `cl /O2 /Ot /EHsc /FC /W4 /nologo /MT`. IDE терпеть ненавижу :) использовать без *особой* необходимости...
Мой вариант с `hypot` - 700±15ms. С вычислением через корень от квадратов - просто охренеть, простите мой французский: примерно 85±15ms. Что ж они туда запихали?! Наверняка какую-то жуткую систему обхода возможных переполнений...

Программа от @KoVadim при тех же условиях компиляции с теми же данными - ну лень ее запускать десяток раз, простите - дала 38 секунд. Ответ другой, но то же самое минимальное расстояние. После исправления `hypot` - 2.7 секунды.

Люди, не пользуйтесь `hypot`!!! :) Кстати, если просто предвычислить таблицу расстояний и брать данные из нее, можно поднять скорость еще раз в 5.

Вот примерные (по одному-двум запускам) результаты в мс:

```
Точек         KoVadim        Harry    Harry (hypot)  Harry (предвычисление
                                                      таблицы расстояний)
  12             230          30          180           12
  13            2700          75          700           24
  14           34700         380         3880           97
  15          484000        1950        23000          414
  16                        9400                      1880
```

**Update2**

Еще для сравнения - полный перебор `hypot` для 13 точек вычисляет 479001600 раз, мой - 8302951...

**Update3**

Последний вариант см. здесь - [Как правильно распараллелить программу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624013/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83)

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что hypot рекомендовали не использовать, т. к. он медленный... Проверь, какое время получится без него?

Comment: Вы программу KoVadim в дебаге или в релизе запускали? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov  Мои стандартные ключики для всякого рода "наколенных" программ - `cl /O2 /Ot /EHsc /FC /W4 /nologo /MT`

Comment: @Qwertiy См. дополнение к ответу.

Comment: _"Ответ другой, но то же самое минимальное расстояние"_ - а в условии просили лексикографически наименьшее из равных, так что кто-то из вас не по условию решает :)

Comment: А сделай вместо двух столбиков с результатами 4 - для каждого решения с hypot и без :)

Comment: Не хочу - не дождусь! :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Блин... Я когда-нибудь научусь внимательно читать условия задач?... Всю жизнь страдаю. Ладно, у меня все равно полный перебор, так что по порядку величины будет примерно то же самое - одинаковых маршрутов не слишком много, лексикографическая проверка быстрая...

Comment: @Qwertiy Подправил, особой разницы на паре пусков не заметил (типа, 1950 vs 2020 или 9400 vs 9800). Так что результаты не исправляю.

Comment: @Qwertiy Добавил предвычисление таблицы расстояний - скорость выросла еще почти в 5 раз...

Comment: @Harry, круто!!!

Comment: Кстати, а в мой свежий [вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624073/178988) по плюсам не заглядывал?