# Как правильно распараллелить программу?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, производительность

В качестве ответа на вопрос [Какой алгоритм использовать для решения задачи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622980/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8/623110#623110) написал свою программку (приведена ниже) - ветвления с отсечением.
Бывает, меня, как поющего Кобзона :), не остановить - словом, мне захотелось выжать все, что можно. В однопоточном режиме, как мне кажется, выжал все, что мог (но, конечно, дальнейшее ускорение приветствуется). Захотел попробовать ускорить за счет параллельности - и вот тут я застрял. Любой из вариантов у меня оказывался резко хуже однопоточного.

Начал я с того, что создавал потоков по количеству ядер. Каждый поток поочередно (с синхронизацией с помощью мьютексов) брал очередную ветвь на первом уровне и полностью обрабатывал ее. Получилось плохо, как как каждая ветвь отрабатывалась полностью независимо, т.е. искалось полное решение для нее - в то время как она, быть может, была бы отброшена сразу - из-за наличия другой более короткой ветви.

Далее сделал общим значение достигнутого минимума среди всех потоков - но это значение опять же пришлось защищать мьютексом, и это привело к очередному увеличению времени работы.

Посему хотелось бы посмотреть на то, как эту задачу решат реальные эксперты в области многопоточности (к каковым себя отнести ну никак не могу).

Так сказать, конкурс на **самый быстрый** вариант. Интересуют именно **параллельные вычисления**.

А вот обещанный однопоточный код (да, я знаю, что он написан ужасно - обсуждается не это, ладно?):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct pnt { double x, y; };

using distance_t = vector<vector<double>>;

struct Func
{
    long long calls;
    double min;              // Текущее минимальное расстояние
    vector<int>        save; // Сохраненная перестановка
    const distance_t  &dist; // Расстония между точками

    Func(const distance_t& dist, const vector<pnt>& x):dist(dist)
    {
        calls = 0;
        min = 0.0;
        // Инициализация путем 0-1-2-...
        save.push_back(0);
        for(size_t i = 1; i < x.size(); ++i)
        {
            min += dist[i-1][i];
            save.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    // Проверка ветви
    bool operator()(const vector<int>& x, size_t l, double cur)
    {
        ++calls;
        // Режем все, где неверный конец (неверное начало невозможно)
        if (l != x.size()-1 && x[l] == int(x.size() - 1)) return false;

        // Текущая длина + расстояние до последней точки, если еще не достали
        if (l != x.size()-1) cur += dist[x[l]][x.size()-1];

        // Если больше минимальной - режем эту ветвь
        if (cur > min + min*DBL_EPSILON) return false;
        // Сохранение нового пути
        if (l == x.size()-1)
        {
            if (abs(min-cur) < min*DBL_EPSILON)
            {
                // Только лексикографически меньший путь
                if (save > x) save = x;
            }
            else
            {
                min = cur;
                save = x;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

// Ветвление и обрезка
bool branches(size_t N, Func& f, const distance_t& dist, size_t level = 1,
              vector<int>*v_ = nullptr, double cur_dist = 0.0)
{
    // Вспомогательный вектор перестановок пути
    vector<int> * vv = (level == 1) ? new vector<int> : v_;
    if (level == 1) for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) vv->push_back(i);
    vector<int>& v = *vv;

    for(size_t i = level; i < N; ++i)
    {
        // Очередная перестановка
        std::swap(v[level],v[i]);
        // Длина для нее
        double length = cur_dist + dist[v[level]][v[level-1]];
        if (f(v,level,length) && level < N-1) branches(N,f,dist,level+1,vv,length);
        // Возвращаем все, как было
        std::swap(v[i],v[level]);
    }
    if (level == 1) delete vv;
    return true;
}


int main(/*int argc, const char * argv[]*/)
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<pnt> x;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        // cout <<"Point " << (i+1) << ": ";
        double xx, yy;
        cin >> xx >> yy;
        x.push_back(pnt{xx,yy});
    }

    distance_t dist(N,vector<double>(N,0.0));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for(int j = i+1; j < N; ++j)
            dist[i][j] = dist[j][i] = sqrt((x[i].x-x[j].x)*(x[i].x-x[j].x)+
                                           (x[i].y-x[j].y)*(x[i].y-x[j].y));

    Func f(dist,x);
    branches(N,f,dist);
    cout << "\n" << f.min << endl;
    for(auto i: f.save) cout << (i+1) << "  ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Calls Func(): " << setw(12) << f.calls << endl;

}
```

Comment: А профайлером смотрели, где основной затык? Кстати, для вычисления расстояние для декартовой плоскости есть функция `hypot`. Оу ... вижу [комменты](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622980/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8/623110#comment869072_623024) про его медлительность.

Comment: главный затык - в кол-ве итераций. А так как задача то NP - то... тут все очень интересно.

Comment: @alexolut В первом варианте отладочный вывод показал огромное количество итераций, тут и думать нечего. Во втором - практически 100% на мьютексах, хотя профайлером и не лазил. Просто этих итераций очень много, и если в каждой смотреть значение `min` с использованием мьютекса, то уже понятно, что ничего хорошего тут и быть не может...

Comment: @KoVadim Ну можем договориться о конкретном тестовом примере. Например, я гонял на точках `x_i = i%4`, `y_i = i/4` - 16-18 штук примерно.

Comment: @alexolut Прогнал профилировщиком. Тормоз есть на мьютексе, но этот тормоз не настолько большой. При этом число вызовов функции оценки и обрезания резко возрастает. Что в совокупности с мьютексами и дает хороший тормоз...

Comment: Дело в том, что сам алгоритм должен быть параллельным, то есть это должно быть другое решение.

Comment: @Cerbo Давайте просто из обычной логики. Если запустим один поток и считаем всю задачу - время-то не должно быть больше? Если запустим два потока, в котором один раньше наткнется на оптимальное решение - второй не должен же считать дольше, чем в однопоточном варианте? Я же не прошу добиться ускорения в N раз, где N - число процессоров, но хоть какое-то ускорение должно получиться?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в мультипоточности важен принцип существования независимых контекстов - т.е имеется определенная работа которую нужно сделать, не зависящую от результатов работы в других потоках. Если это не удовлетворимо, то начинается всякая мутотень с мъютексами и кросс-потоковыми сообщениями, семафорами и др. что в итоге создаёт неудобноваримый код, который работал бы быстрее в одном потоке, не ломая людям мозги.

Comment: Там, где `for`, должен быть и openmp - https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP

Comment: есть ещё такой Intel TBB, imho на порядок лучше OpenMP

Comment: Вот статья хорошая: www.hpcc.unn.ru/file.php?id=373

Comment: Тут дело такое, я конечно специалист по параллельным вычислениям, но первое, что бросилось в глаза - крайне неоптимальный алгоритм самого решения. Вот все пишут, что "NP", "перебор", все дела. На самом деле задача может быть решена гораздо быстрее методом динамического программирования по подмножествам. И работать это будет куда быстрее даже на одном ядре какого-нибудь древнего калькулятора, чем вот при таком параллельном алгоритме. Вот статья, где есть пример задачи, похожей на вашу: https://habr.com/ru/post/191498/ Вот как раз такой алгоритм и параллелить проще. Мало ли, пригодится вам.

Comment: По оптимизации... Мда..
dist[i][j] = dist[j][i] = ... а ты тут циклы в половиеу сократить не хочешь, если идёшь по диагонали?(сам догадаешься думаю как... обычно вообще не заполняется одна из частей матрицы симметричной) Не юзай пушбэки, если знаешь размер. Много всякого ещё, но тебя это видимо не интересует... По паралельности... Не пользуй мьютексы, пользуй атомики. А вообще Потоки, Ядра и прочее, это из пушки по воробьям. Циклы лучше паралель через openMP.

Comment: Поддерживаю @Zealint и запрашиваю данные для проверки. Ну или скажите, где чувак с исходного вопроса запускал свои решения.

Comment: Самый эффективный вариант, пожалуй, написать собственную систему параллельных вычислений (Job System). В общих чертах такая система представляет из себя N рабочих потоков (N - число ядер CPU) и очередь задач. Каждый поток в цикле извлекает из очереди задачу и выполняет её. Каждая задача (её удобно реализовать в виде класса) может: а) порождать другие задачи, добавляя их в очередь задач; б) временно приостанавливать своё выполнение до завершения других задач (при этом рабочий поток  тут же преступает к выполнению следующей задачи из очереди). Однако это работа далеко не на один вечер!..

Answer (score 1):

Вот как надо:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

#define DBL_EPSILON 0.0000000000001

struct pnt { double x, y; };

using distance_t = vector<vector<double>>;

struct Func
{
    long long calls;
    double min;              // Текущее минимальное расстояние
    vector<int>        save; // Сохраненная перестановка
    const distance_t  &dist; // Расстония между точками

    Func(const distance_t& dist, const vector<pnt>& x):dist(dist)
    {
        calls = 0;
        min = 0.0;
        // Инициализация путем 0-1-2-...
        save.push_back(0);
        for(size_t i = 1; i < x.size(); ++i)
        {
            min += dist[i-1][i];
            save.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    // Проверка ветви
    bool operator()(const vector<int>& x, size_t l, double cur)
    {
        ++calls;
        // Режем все, где неверный конец (неверное начало невозможно)
        if (l != x.size()-1 && x[l] == int(x.size() - 1)) return false;

        // Текущая длина + расстояние до последней точки, если еще не достали
        if (l != x.size()-1) cur += dist[x[l]][x.size()-1];

        // Если больше минимальной - режем эту ветвь
        if (cur > min + min*DBL_EPSILON) return false;
        // Сохранение нового пути
        if (l == x.size()-1)
        {
            if (abs(min-cur) < min*DBL_EPSILON)
            {
                // Только лексикографически меньший путь
                if (save > x) save = x;
            }
            else
            {
                min = cur;
                save = x;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

// Ветвление и обрезка
bool branches(size_t N, Func& f, const distance_t& dist, size_t level = 1,
              vector<int>*v_ = nullptr, double cur_dist = 0.0)
{
    // Вспомогательный вектор перестановок пути
    vector<int> * vv = (level == 1) ? new vector<int> : v_;
    if (level == 1) for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) vv->push_back(i);
    vector<int>& v = *vv;

    for(size_t i = level; i < N; ++i)
    {
        // Очередная перестановка
        std::swap(v[level],v[i]);
        // Длина для нее
        double length = cur_dist + dist[v[level]][v[level-1]];
        if (f(v,level,length) && level < N-1) branches(N,f,dist,level+1,vv,length);
        // Возвращаем все, как было
        std::swap(v[i],v[level]);
    }
    if (level == 1) delete vv;
    return true;
}


int main(/*int argc, const char * argv[]*/)
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<pnt> x;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        // cout <<"Point " << (i+1) << ": ";
        double xx, yy;
        cin >> xx >> yy;
        x.push_back(pnt{xx,yy});
    }

    distance_t dist(N,vector<double>(N,0.0));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for(int j = i+1; j < N; ++j)
            dist[i][j] = dist[j][i] = sqrt((x[i].x-x[j].x)*(x[i].x-x[j].x)+
                                           (x[i].y-x[j].y)*(x[i].y-x[j].y));

    Func f(dist,x);
    branches(N,f,dist);
    cout << "\n" << f.min << endl;
    for(auto i: f.save) cout << (i+1) << "  ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Calls Func(): " << setw(12) << f.calls << endl;

}
```

А вот ошибки:
надо `#include <math.h>` добавить и задать `DBL_EPSILON`.

Comment: Ой. Я уже и забыл, это было так давно... Надо сесть, восстановить и посмотреть. В любом случае спасибо :)